# How to Check if a list item is checked in the console

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm looking to check in the console which checkboxes have been selected. Even though I'm checking the check boxes, it is still returning 'not checked' in the console.

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.specializations-list'));

list.forEach(function (listItems) {
    if (listItems.checked) {
        console.log('checked');
    } else {
        console.log('not checked');
    }
})
```

```html
 <form class="form">

                <div class="specializations-list">
                        <div class="list-items">
                
                <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value = "Item-1">Item-1
                        <br>

                <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-2">Item-2
                        <br>   
                       
                <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-3">Item-3
                        </div>   

                                                
                <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-4" >Item-4
                        <br>

                <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-5" >Item-5
                         <br>     
                       
                <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-6">Item-6
           
                </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You're looping on wrong element, to check checked or not you need to check `checked` property on `input` element, whereas right now you're checking on div with class `specializations-list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event.target and an event listener on the change of the checkbox.

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']"));

function check(e){
if (e.target.checked) {
      console.log(`${e.target.value} is checked`);
    } 
}

list.forEach(function(listItems) {
  listItems.addEventListener('change', check)
})
```

```html
<form class="form">

  <div class="specializations-list">
    <div class="list-items">

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-1">Item-1
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-2">Item-2
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-3">Item-3
    </div>


    <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-4">Item-4
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-5">Item-5
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-6">Item-6

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, this worked! Thank you @dale landry

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're looping on wrong element, to check checked or not you need to check `checked` property on input element, whereas right now you're checking on div with class `specializations-list`

```js
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.specializations-list  input[type="checkbox"]'));
    list.forEach(function (listItems) {
        if (listItems.checked) {
            console.log('checked', listItems.value);
        } else {
            console.log('not checked', listItems.value);
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<form class="form">
      <div class="specializations-list">
       <div class="list-items">

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value = "Item-1">Item-1
              <br>

      <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-2">Item-2
              <br>   

      <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-3">Item-3
              </div>   


      <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-4" >Item-4
              <br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-5" >Item-5
               <br>     

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-6">Item-6

      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Code Maniac. What does "window" do?

Comment: @WeeklyButterfly34 i've just added a event listener for click event to the changes dynamically for demo

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the div element. You have to query the input element instead of div element.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking your div in querySelectorAll. use this instead

```
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.specializations-list 
input[type=checkbox]'));
```